# How to use youtube-dl --cookies

Tags: macos, video, youtube, cookies

How do I use the `--cookies` option to `youtube-dl` to download a Youtube video?  Can anyone provide a worked example of how to obtain the relevant cookies for Youtube and put it in the appropriate format for `youtube-dl`?

Context: I want to download a private Youtube video.  For various reasons, the method of logging into my Google account is complicated and involves two-factor authentication and not supported by `youtube-dl`'s existing command-line options.  Therefore, it seems the best way is to log in manually in my browser, obtain the authentication cookies somehow, and use the `--cookies` option -- but I can't find a worked example of how to do this.

Comment: Did you try generating an app password in your google account dashboard and using that when providing your credentials to YouTube-dl?

Comment: a fresh version of youtube-dl (from their just reinstated GitHub repo) works for me with Google's 2FA (put the app-specific password you can generate on the command line, as `-2 XXXXXXXXX`)

Comment: This question does not seem to be related to macOS in any way.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Once you get the cookies, you only need to run
`youtube-dl --cookies /pathtocookiefile`

If you use Chrome and accept third-party plugins to read your cookies.
Just try a [`Get cookies.txt` chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/cookies.txt), open the youtube then export the cookies using the plugin.

If you want do it manual in Chrome. F12 >  Application > Storage > Cookies.
You need convert cookie list to `Netscape format cookies file`

```
#domain          HTTP/Secure    Expires      Name Value  
.youtube.com     TRUE/FALSE    1548523767    GPS    1
```

Comment: The linked extension was removed. There's another one with similar functionality: [Get cookies.txt](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/get-cookiestxt/bgaddhkoddajcdgocldbbfleckgcbcid)

Comment: @Athari That one is also removed.

Comment: @slhck The current solution is to use `--cookies-from-browser BROWSER[+KEYRING][:PROFILE][::CONTAINER]`, see https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/456906/4558. If you still need cookies.txt, try [any of the current extensions](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/cookies.txt).

Answer (score 29):

While this may not work for YouTube specifically, I wanted to highlight an easier approach that works well for `youtube-dl` to download from a site that requires login (and uses cookies to track the session).

*Edit: Unfortunately [YouTube is dependent on cookies set across multiple domains](https://daveparrish.net/posts/2018-06-22-How-to-download-private-YouTube-videos-with-youtube-dl.html), so this approach probably will not work there.*

youtube-dl has [an option called `--add-header`](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#workarounds):

```
--add-header FIELD:VALUE         Specify a custom HTTP header and its value, separated by a colon ':'. You can use this option
                                 multiple times
```

Cookies are ultimately just submitted to the server as HTTP headers, so all you have to do is set the `Cookie` header on the request. This method is also quite a bit easier than extracting a cookie jar from a modern browser, especially since those tend to be encrypted and people often turn to questionable 3rd party tools to extract that data.

Here is a usage example:

```
youtube-dl --add-header "Cookie:COOKIE_STRING_EXTRACTED_FROM_BROWSER" "https://website-that-hosts.example/the-video-you-want"
```

To extract the value of the cookie header:

1. Open the website you wish to download from
2. Log in
3. Open your browser's network inspector
4. Reload the page
5. Find the very first request made to that website and click on it, then view the headers for the request
6. Copy the entire string value of the `Cookie` header, highlighted in this image:

   [image: Extracting the Cookie header from Google Chrome]
7. Paste that value into the example command above to replace `COOKIE_STRING_EXTRACTED_FROM_BROWSER` (inside the quotes)

This works well to download full episodes from sites that require cable provider login.

Comment: Works well on Ubuntu and with the fork [yt-dlp](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp)

Comment: Works not for me, as I still get
ERROR: Join this channel to get access to members-only content like this video,
and other exclusive perks.

Comment: It works for me like this: youtube-dl --add-header Cookie:"COOKIE_STRING"

Answer (score 14):

This approach doesn't require installing any browser extension, which could pose a [security risk](https://www.howtogeek.com/188346/why-browser-extensions-can-be-dangerous-and-how-to-protect-yourself/), as @bgentry also [pointed out](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/360619/70132).

It requires a terminal window, [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/download/), and this open-source script I [published](https://github.com/dandv/convert-chrome-cookies-to-netscape-format).

1. Download [the script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dandv/convert-chrome-cookies-to-netscape-format/master/convert-cookies.js) (or clone [the repo](https://github.com/dandv/convert-chrome-cookies-to-netscape-format) if you prefer)
2. In an editor, open a new blank file
3. In Chrome/Chromium, launch Developer Tools (F12)
4. Navigate to the site you need cookies from, e.g. YouTube, and log in.
5. Go to Application -> Storage -> Cookies
6. For each URL under Cookies (e.g. `https://www.youtube.com`), copy the table of cookies into the clipboard, then paste it at the end of the file you've opened in step 2.  [image: Chrome cookies] *NOTE: Ensure long cookies are intact, copy/paste directly to repair any that were cut off if needed. [cutoff will include … symbol, can search for it with ctrl+f]*
7. Save the file with a name like `file-with-cookies-copy-pasted-from-Chrome.txt`
8. Run the script:

   ```
    node convert-cookies.js file-with-cookies-copy-pasted-from-Chrome.txt > netscape-cookies.txt
   ```

Now, `netscape-cookies.txt` will contain cookies ready to be used by any application that reads cookies in Netscape format (e.g. `yotube-dl` or `curl`).

Comment: Note: the input txt file must be encoded in UTF-8, weird results if Unicode

Comment: @dan-dascalescu When the "Copy" item does not appear in the right-clik menu, just press the "shift" key BEFORE right-click to open the context menu.

Comment: @dan-dascalescu One can also use this command to convert the cookies to the Nescape jar cookies format : `curl -o /dev/null -s --cookie file-with-cookies-copy-pasted-from-Chrome.txt --cookie-jar netscape-cookies.txt https://www.youtube.com`

Answer (score 14):

This answer doesn't require an extension and is mostly automatic.

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to open Web Developer Tools
2. Select the **Console** tab at the top of the Web Developer Tools window
3. Copy this code into the console input and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

```js
(function() {
  let S = '# Netscape HTTP Cookie File\n';
  for (raw_cookie of document.cookie.split(';')) {
    let cookie = raw_cookie.trim();
    let separator = cookie.indexOf('=');
    let name = cookie.substring(0, separator);
    let value = cookie.substring(separator + 1);

    let domain = window.location.hostname;
    // hopefully this will convert domains like `www.test.com` and `test.com` into `.test.com`
    domain = domain.replace('www.', '.');
    if (domain[0] !== '.') {
        domain = '.' + domain;
    }

    // netscape cookie file format:
    // # domain  HTTP PATH SECURE timestamp name  value
    // .test.com TRUE /    FALSE  123456789 token 1234abcdef
    S += `${domain}\tTRUE\t/\tTRUE\t0\t${name}\t${value}\n`
  }

  console.log(S)
})();
```

4. Right-click on output and select **Copy Message**
5. Create `cookies.txt` and paste output there
6. I also had to delete the last line which said something like this: `debugger eval code:21:11`

I've tested this method with Firefox on twitch.tv and successfully used the resulting file with `youtube-dl 2021.06.06`

PS: Don't forget to remove HttpOnly attributes from the cookies before running the function (in Chrome: DevTools>Application>Cookies>{URL}, uncheck the checkboxes in HttpOnly column). Otherwise, HttpOnly cookies won't show up in the output of the function and this may lead to authorization errors.

Comment: While this is cool, for some reason yt-dlp didn't work with cookies, but it did work on crunchyrolll when I used the `-u` username and password option.

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly with Safari.

Answer (score 7):

While this is not a direct answer to the question, it's a much better solution: you can use a fork of youtube-dl called [yt-dlp](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp) that can directly load cookies from browser databases using `--cookies-from-browser firefox` or `--cookies-from-browser chrome` so no need to export at all!

Answer (score 4):

Since all of the Chrome extensions for cookies are closed-source…

1. F12 → Application → Storage → Cookies
2. Select everything manually and copy to some text file
3. `$ cat /tmp/some-text-file.txt | awk 'BEGIN{print "# Netscape HTTP Cookie File"}{sub(/^[^.]/,".&",$3);print $3"\tTRUE\t/\tTRUE\t0\t"$1"\t"$2}' > /tmp/cookies.txt`